# How to deal with Lightning input IDs changing in browser plugin?

Tags: lightning, javascript, jquery, aura

I'm writing a Chrome plugin that fills data into some fields in the Salesforce Lightning "New Lead" page.

Looking at the  elements on the page it seems impossible to figure out which one is the "Mobile" number, for example. Here's an example

```
<input class=" input" maxlength="40" type="tel" aria-describedby="" placeholder="" id="1930:0" data-aura-rendered-by="1934:0" data-interactive-lib-uid="38">
```

At first glance I want to do something like this:

```
document.getElementById("1930:0")
```

But the next time I reload the page the ID of the Mobile input is **7:4790;a**, and the next time again it's a different, random sequence.

I clearly don't understand how this form is being generated or how to figure it out, but I suspect it has to do with aura, which I also don't know much about.

Can anyone help me locate the Mobile field using javascript/jQuery?

Answer (score 0):

If this form is created by you, then you can hardcode the id for this element(make sure its unique in this html page)

If this is not your form, try to getElementByTagName('input') this will give you can array of elements check which element has attribute of type=tel. This is your element.

Example

```
getElementByTagName('input').forEach(function(eachElement){
    if(eachElement.getAttribute("type")=='tel'){
      //your logic will go here
    }
});
```

Note : This code is not tested just a Pseudocode

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. The form is not created by me, it's the Lightning "New Lead" form. And unfortunately there are multiple inputs with type=tel, so I still need to find e.g. the Mobile phone. I'd love any insight on how the IDs get generated. I'm not very familiar with the Aura framework, etc.